# First Order Logic Set Notation for clauses

Tags: notation, first-order-logic

I found a set of clauses expressed in this way in first order logic :

$\left \{ \left \{ -p,q \right \},\left \{ r \right \} \right \}$

I have never seen this kind of formalism, so i ask your help to understand it.

What i think is that the outer comma represent an AND, while the inner comma represent an OR . Is correct ?

Comment: Yes, it is. See [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)). And see Mordechai Ben-Ari, [Mathematical Logic for Computer Science](https://books.google.it/books?id=TQ1n03kEBOkC&pg=PA77), Springer (3rd ed 2012), page 77.

Comment: Thanks so much Mauro :) I'm also italian (i'm a curious student)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.

See [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)), as well as : Mordechai Ben-Ari, [Mathematical Logic for Computer Science](https://books.google.it/books?id=TQ1n03kEBOkC&pg=PA77), Springer (3rd ed 2012), page 77.

The set of [clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)) $\{ \{ \lnot p, q \},\{ r \} \}$ is the clausal form of the [CNF formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) :

> $(\lnot p \lor q) \land r$.